# How to get the total items in Context to reflect in Template in Django List View

Tags: django, django-views

I am working on an E-commerce project and I got lost in the middle to generate some kind of a report to get the total no. of a sold item after payment is made.

When the order is paid `ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)` become `True`

I have tried to add the context with the total sold but it didn't work so I kept it in the code below but commented it.

Here is the Item models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is the OrderItemmodels.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class DesignerOnlyPostListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "designer_only_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Item.objects.filter(designer=user).order_by('-timestamp')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        comments = Comment.objects.all()
        # total_sold = Order.objects.all()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["total_comments"] = comments.count()
        # context["total_sold"] = total_sold.count()
        return context
```

Here is the template

```
{% for item in items %}
<tr>
    <td>No. of Sold:</td>
    <td>{{ item.total_sold.all.count }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem in your template, you want to display total sold for each "item". In my opinion, i will add a method to `Item`, this approaching help you add custom filters as you want, something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # ...
    def count_sold(self):
        return self.order_set.filter(ordered=True).count()
```

And in view:

```
<td>{{ item.count_sold }}</td>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Could you clarify order_set? as I got `'Item' object has no attribute 'order_set'`

Comment: between Order and Item is ManyToMany, so `order_set` is a magic of Django ORM that help you get queryset of Order with filter Item :p, example:
`an_item.orderitem_set.all() is same as OrderItem.objects.filter(item=an_item)`

Comment: I am getting `'Item' object has no attribute 'order_set'` error how to fix it ? the many to many relation is between order and order item